# Which of .emacs or init.el is evaluated first?

Tags: init-file

Which is evaluated first .emacs or init.el?

And if there are conflicting statements which is used?

Comment: See [How Emacs finds your initialization file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html) in the manual.

Comment: Note that only *ONE* init file is ever loaded: the first one found in the sequence described in the link above.