# Why is emacs looking in `~/` for `.emacs`?

Tags: init-file

I'm using /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/.emacs

as my initialisation file. When I start emacs I get:-

Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘~/.emacs’:

Why is emacs looking in '~/` for .emacs?

Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: What did you do to set up `/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/.emacs` as your init file? Do you have a file called `.emacs` in your home directory? See [How Emacs looks for its init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html)

Comment: Originally I created a ~/.emacs file but then moved it to 

/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/.emacs

There is no .emacs file anywhere else. Neither is there an init.el 

This is with emacs 29.1.

Comment: If you do `ls -la ~/.emacs` at a shell prompt, what do you get?

Comment: why are you doing this? what documentation have you seen that makes you think you can use `/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/.emacs` as an initialization file.

Comment: root@FreeBSD:/ # find / -name .emacs -print
/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/.emacs

Comment: Emacs always looks for `.emacs`in the home directory. If it does not find it there, it proceeds to alternate directories and names, as detailed in the link. The fact that you get an error while loading `~/.emacs` means that Emacs finds *something* there, tries to load it and it gets an error. Try `M-: (load user-init-file)` and see what that says. In any case, I cannot reproduce the error you get. As for `/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/.emacs`, Emacs will not look there unless you've mucked around with `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`and even then it will look for `init.el` there, not `.emacs`.

Comment: Also, as @nega implies, putting a user initialization file in a shared directory is a bad idea.

Comment: If I have a /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/site-start.el and I try to load abcxyz.el without any path where can I place it? If it's in ~/.emacs.d/ should I expect it to be found?

Comment: The comments on your question https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/78721 three days earlier linked to a very clear explanation in the manual. It doesn't seem as if you read that documentation.